# How can I get "jan-2018, Feb-2018, Mar-2018" as dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get month and year together in drop down list, and month list should show next 3 months list, example if current month is January 2018 then the drop down list should show Jan-2018, Feb-2018, Mar-2018.

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this?

```
Jan-2018 
Feb-2018
Mar-2018
```

Comment: I am coding an answer. but the solution depends. If you read the value of the selected value, is it then sufficient if you have only the text "Feb-2018" or do you then need the DateTime?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ yourSelectList.Add(new SelectListItem{ Value = i, Text = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(i).ToString("MMM-yyyy") }); }`

Comment: Usually, Stack Overflow is _not_ a free coding service, but is intended to help you for an issue you do have in your existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to use `Enumerable.Range` and get the correct month names with `GetMonthName` in `DateTimeFormatInfo`

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(i).Substring(0, 3) + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year)).ToList();
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "key";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "value";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

The value field of the DDL is still an integer 1 - 12, so you can easily work with months in code behind.

UPDATE

If you want from the current month onward, use

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Select(i => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i+1).Month).Substring(0, 3) + "-" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).Year)).ToList();
```

Comment: As i understand the question: if you execute the code today (23th october 2018) then "Nov-2018", "Dec-2018", "Jan-2019" is expected. Thats the tricky about it :-)

Comment: @gofal3 not really tricky. Just change the code to suit your needs. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>> GetNextMonts(int number)
    {
        DateTime month = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            month = month.AddMonths(1);
            yield return new KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>(month, month.ToString("MMM-yyyy"));
        }
    }
```

This code returns a bindable list of the next monts. To be used as in the answer of VDWWD.